# Incorrect value when adding double to the end of a string

Tags: java, string, casting, double

I'm having an issue adding a double value to the end of a string.

Here's the code:

```
String priceString = "The total is £";
double price = 8.64532;

System.out.println(String.format("%.2f", price)); //Correct value

priceString = priceString + price;
System.out.println(priceString); // Incorrect value
```

I've also tried:

```
System.out.println(priceString + String.format("%.2f", price)); //Incorrect
```

The output from the first print statement is correct:

```
8.64
```

But the output from the second print statement is always :

```
0.008.64
```

I have no idea what is happening or why.

** Edit ** I've noticed that this site is INCREDIBLY hostile to beginners. I'd been searching for a solution for hours and, after receiving no response from my Uni lecturers, NEEDED to post somewhere to get some help. Not everyone knows everything and sometimes beginners need to ask you more experienced devs questions. Searching the site offered no useful results, hence the post.

**Edit 2**
The code works fine in other IDE's, so the issue appears to be with my IDE. I'd posted here because I couldn't find an answer anywhere and, obviously, was more inclined to believe the issue was me than the IDE.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://ideone.com/v4yots).

Comment: Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and [edit] your question accordingly.  See also: [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @Joe C         I asked here because I couldn't find the answer anywhere else and because I'm a beginner. The output that I get from debuggers doesn't always make sense to me. In particular, the debugger in the IDE that I'm forced to use by my university. My lecturers are also of ZERO help.

Comment: If the output from debuggers doesn't make sense to you, then a question about this output would be a valid question to ask.

Comment: @Andy Turner   That's bizarre. Maybe it's the terrible IDE that I'm using?

Comment: @JoeC          I'm not asking a question about debugger output because I don't want to. I'm asking why this isn't working when, as far as I can tell, it should be. As Andy said, this works for him and it doesn't for me in my IDE, but does using the site he linked. It seems to be an IDE problem to me.

I'm inexperienced enough that I'd assumed it was something that I was doing wrong, but that doesn't appear to be the case for once. I wanted to have a human being explain what was wrong and how I could fix it, not the useless and un-educational output of a debugger.

Answer (score -1):

Is that the full code?
Seems like you could be confusing some variables and printing a double with value of 0.00 then concatenating the correct price value.

Comment: That's what I'd initially thought too. But I've checked the value of every variable after assignment via a debugger and print statements. The variables all perfect. It happens immediately on 'casting' the double to a string.